# Scroll over a div and animate another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have 1 to 6 divs that are created dynamically. I also have nested divs inside of these that I want to animate when I scroll over the parent div.  Right now when I scroll over it animates all the divs, How would I send each one as an argument?

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qNBEJ/2/) with my code

```
<div class="animate" id="indexJoinBanner" > 
  Roll over this should animate move1
    <div class="move">move1XXXXXXXXXXXXX</div>
  </div>
  <div class="animate" id="indexJoinBanner" > 
  Roll over this should animate move2
    <div class="move">move2XXXXXXXXXXXXX</div>
  </div>
  <div class="animate" id="indexJoinBanner" > 
  Roll over this should animate move3
    <div class="move">move3XXXXXXXXXXXXX</div>
  </div>




<script>
 $('.animate').on('mouseover', function () {
   $('.move').animate({
     left: "0px",
   },500 );
 }).on('mouseout', function () {
   $('.move').animate({
     left: "-150px",
   },500 );
 })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.  The problem is that `mouseoever`/`mouseout` get triggered when you move between child elements, which you don't want.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/qNBEJ/3/

Comment: awesome, that works,  what if I wanted to do something like this? [link](http://jsfiddle.net/qNBEJ/5/)

Comment: @vinylDeveloper target the specific `.move` element.  Just `$(".move")` finds all `.move`s.  http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/qNBEJ/6/

Answer (score 0):

By calling `$('.move')` you're searching for all elements with class move in document and you want to animate only child elements of currently hovered element. Also its better to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` (see documentation: [mouseenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mouseenter) and [mouseleave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mouseleave))

```
$('.animate').each(function () {
    var self = $(this),
        move = self.find('.move');
    self.on('mouseenter', function () {
        move.animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, 500);
    }).on('mouseleave', function () {
        move.animate({
            left: "-150px"
        }, 500);
    });
});
```